# Converter name URI with special characters from PostgreSQL function to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I need to convert a function from `PostgreSQL` to`MySql`. I need to remove the special characters from a string uri.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name2uri(text)
RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
STRICT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT REPLACE(TRIM(regexp_replace(translate(   
    LOWER($1),
    'áàâãäåāăąèééêëēĕėęěìíîïìĩīĭḩóôõöōŏőùúûüũūŭůäàáâãåæçćĉčöòóôõøüùúûßéèêëýñîìíïş',
    'aaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiihooooooouuuuuuuuaaaaaaeccccoooooouuuuseeeeyniiiis'
), '[^a-z0-9\-]+', ' ', 'g')),' ', '-');
$$;
```

how do I do that? Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS translate;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION translate(subject varchar(255), what varchar(255), replace_to varchar(255)) 
RETURNS varchar(255)
 DETERMINISTIC
begin
 declare c int unsigned default 0;
 declare result varchar(255);

 set result = subject;

 while c <= length(subject) do
  set result = replace(result, mid(what, c, 1), mid(replace_to, c, 1) );
  set c=c+1;   
 end while;

 return result; 
end
```

and

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS name2uri;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION name2uri(i text)
RETURNS longtext
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN

declare result longtext;
set result =  REPLACE(TRIM(regexp_replace(translate(
    LOWER(i),
    'áàâãäåāăąèééêëēĕėęěìíîïìĩīĭḩóôõöōŏőùúûüũūŭůäàáâãåæçćĉčöòóôõøüùúûßéèêëýñîìíïş',
    'aaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiihooooooouuuuuuuuaaaaaaeccccoooooouuuuseeeeyniiiis'
), '[^a-z0-9-]+', ' ',1,0,'c')),' ', '-');

return result;
end
```

select name2uri(' fáBIO    rodrígues') `with space before or after the string comes out ok! --> fabio-rodrigues`

select name2uri('fáBIO    rodrígues') `without space before or after the string quits not ok! --> fabio-rodr-gues (the char i is replace by -)`

Why did not correctly replace the `í` character with `i`?